# Meteor Deployment via MUP

Tags: meteor, deployment, mup

I am trying to deploy my app via [MUP](https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up) ,everything works fine except when I run command `mup deploy`. In browser website loads but it does not shows the latest changes I have made. Build files has all changes that I have made.I am using Amazon EC2 for server.

Edit:

In MUP logs it shows that server has started on port 80. I also checked the build file it has latest code but somehow server is not rendering in browser.I am not sure its issue of MUP Or meteor build or amazon EC2 server.
[image]

Comment: This question needs a bit more clarity as it's generic in nature.

Comment: The question is not clear. Does MUP show you success message?

Comment: I have updated question with @mostafizrahman

Comment: you are using the wrong or outdated version from mup.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm having the exact same problem, I can clarify the question.

I'm using Mup build 1.2.8/latest on Windows 10, Meteor v1.4.4.2/latest, deploying to Ubuntu 14.04 on Digital Ocean.

Doing "mup.cmd deploy" builds the bundle, pushes it to the server, starts the app and verifies the deployment, all successfully. The meteor logs as shown by "mup.cmd logs" shows the app started successfully (other than the Kadira warning which should be fixed in the newly deployed version). Browsing to my app doesn't show any of my recent changes (they do show up when running locally). It seems as if the updated container isn't the one running. I've tried starting, stopping and removing the Docker container to no avail.

For reference, here is the mup.js file I'm using (with the names changed to protect the guilty). This file worked to deploy fine 6 weeks ago.

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: '1.2.3.4',
      username: 'Ron',
      pem: '/cygwin64/home/Ron/.ssh/id_rsa',
    }
  },

  meteor: {
    name: 'MyApp',
    path: '../',

    servers: {
      one: {}
    },

    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
      debug: true,
      cleanAfterBuild: true,
      buildLocation: '../../output'
    },

    env: {
      // TODO: Change to your app's url
      // If you are using ssl, it needs to start with https://
      ROOT_URL: 'https://MyApp.com',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor'
    },

    docker: {
      // change to 'kadirahq/meteord' if your app is not using Meteor 1.4
      image: 'abernix/meteord:base'
    },

    // This is the maximum time in seconds it will wait
    // for your app to start
    // Add 30 seconds if the server has 512mb of ram
    // And 30 more if you have binary npm dependencies.
    deployCheckWaitTime: 60,

    ssl: {
      autogenerate: {
        email: 'email@example.com',
        domains: 'MyApp.com, www.MyApp.com'
      }
    },

    // Show progress bar while uploading bundle to server
    // You might need to disable it on CI servers
    enableUploadProgressBar: true
  },

  mongo: {
    port: 27017,
    version: '3.4.1',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    }
  }
};
```

**EDIT::**
I deleted all of the containers and images except mongo, ran "mup setup" and "mup deploy" again with exactly the same results, old version is running. So the problem seems to be with the meteor build portion of mup.

**EDIT 2::**
I found at least 1 of the problems. I have the buildLocation set to a relative path. At some point Mup changes the current directory which causes multiple copies of the buildLocation to be used. In my case the output of the Meteor build command (the new files) were in one and Mup was deploying to the server from another one that happened to contain the old files. I changed buildLocation to an absolute path and the new version is being deployed. Yeah! But wait, even though Mup says the verification worked, my app never runs and the container keeps restarting. Looking out the logs I suspect that the problem is with the line below. Somehow the path has a backslash in it. I'm not sure where this is coming from.

> [192.241.229.15]npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   chmod
>   '/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/sshpk/bin\sshpk-conv'

**SOLUTION::** Thanks to Parth Mahida I was inspired to remove the /opt/MyApp directory on the server, as well as removing and reinstalling the sshpk NPM package on my build machine then redid Mup setup and Mup deploy and everything worked again. No idea how the sshpk package became corrupt, but at this point I don't care.

Comment: Hi, I found the problem was on my server I had multiple deployment folders in /opt/. Remove all of them and try to deploy again.